# Can we restart outlook.exe using ::PostMessage() in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, mapi

I want to restart Outlook.exe by passing a commandline parameter in my C++ application.

I have two questions

1. Can we restart it using `::PostMessage()` function if I have the handle to outlook.exe window? Or any other way to achieve it?
2. Can I pass commandline arguments to it?

Comment: The second question is unclear. What is "it" ? You can certainly pass commandline arguments to `Outlook.exe`, but not to a `HANDLE`.

Comment: Yes, by "it", i meant ::PostMessage()

Answer (score 0):

You can post `WM_CLOSE` to Outlook, but that only closes it. You'll need to restart it with something like `CreateProcess`, and that is where you can pass command-line arguments.

Comment: Doesn't the `WM_CLOSE` message close a single window of Outlook? What if Outlook has multiple windows opened (multiple emails in separate inspector windows).

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: IIRC there's one main window, and closing that will close the application. When the question said _the_ handle, I presumed that meant the handle  of that main window.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify command line arguments when your application starts a new process, for example, to start an external application you could use the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
system("cmd.exe")
```

The second argument allows specifying parameters.

However, you need to close Outlook before launching a new instance and applying  the command line argument for clearing the autocomplete list. For that reason, you can develop an external application which can launch Outlook with a specified command line, but that application should be scheduled from your application to run and when the `outlook.exe` process doesn't exist. So, in your application just run it and wait until Outlook goes out from the list of running applications) and close Outlook (see the [Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.quit(method)) method of the `Application` class).

The `WM_CLOSE` message may have any impact on the active window only, so Outlook can remain running if multiple windows are opened. For example, multiple inspector windows are opened.